# Detect style sheet load

Tags: css, web, browser

What are good ways to detect whether a style sheet has loaded using vanilla JavaScript? I understand they do not have the same `load` event that images and scripts fire.

Loading as packed into a .js file (like with WebPack 'loaders') is not an option.

**2022 update:** All major browsers have now supported `onload=` on `<link rel=stylesheet>` tags for years, so that would be the obvious way to detect when CSS has loaded. Not also that external stylesheets in the `head` are blocking during page load, but can be added later with JS to make them asynchronous. It’s that scenario in which my question is relevant.

Test page: https://alanhogan.com/files/async-css/head-async-test-with-js.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `<link>` elements have `load` and `error` events, but they are garanteed only for Chrome, Firefox and Opera. If you don't need to support IE or Safari, I think this is just enough:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="some_style.css" onload="anounceReady()">
   ```

   EDIT: Just tested with IE11 and IE8, `onload` is supported but `onerror` isn't. I have no Mac at hand so I don't know how Safari handles them.
2. If you are going to support browsers don't have `load` event for `<link>` elements, or very old Chrome/Firefox, there is a commonly used easy dirty but working solution. Add a piece of probing rule set at the end of your CSS file, and detect the computed style of a certain probing element (usually invisible) via JavaScript.

   HTML:

   ```
   <div id="probe"></div>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   #probe {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1000;
   }
   ```

   JavaScript:

   ```
   var probeStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('probe'));
   probeStyle.zIndex; // expect "-1000" after CSS is loaded
   ```

Comment: Just leaving a comment to point out that these APIs are now much more reliable, in 2022, than they were in 2014 

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
function checkSheetLoaded (urlSpec) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;

    for (var ii = 0, max = ss.length; ii < max; ii++) {
        if (ss[ii].href.indexOf(urlSpec) >=0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
checkSheetLoaded('foo/bar.css');
```

Basically iterates over the stylesheet collection looking for a string match.

Comment: Doesn't this check to see if the stylesheet link tag is inserted into the document? Isn't that possible without the stylesheet having been downloaded?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be in the Stylesheets collection if it was just a link.  That collection refers to sets of rules, not to an element list.

Comment: I read that this that method worked everywhere but in Firefox. That was 2 years old, however, so maybe it works now. (Firefox now actually supports a load event, too.) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see an issue here — `indexOf` returns `-1`, not `false`, on failure

Comment: Sorry, one of the pitfalls about using multiple languages daily.  You wind up taking the idiosyncrasies of one into the next.  I typically use a bitwise not (!!~(ss.href.indexOf(urlSpec) ) in JS for this.  : )